# Отправка запроса через curl с csrf токеном

Tags: php, curl, csrf

Итак, делаю я бота для одной биржи, и для ответа пользователю нужен "csrf-token", как достать выяснил, написал класс, понял что он как то связан с сессией, переписал класс и тут начиналось то что заставило меня написать вопрос тут.

Почему то по необъяснимым причинам для меня токен просто... не подходит!

Начал думать...
Сделал echo сесии и токена, взял сессию и впихнул её через developer tools в браузер, посмотрел токен в f12(он там в теге body) и он не равен тому что выдал мне скрипт.

Ну и я подумал, и просто вписал сессию в скрипт вместо функции её получения, и скрипт выдал верный токен, точь в точь который в девелопер тулс.

Вопрос, кто то знает из-за чего такое может быть? Может это какая то защита от ботов? Если да то как её можно обойти?

Comment: Токен обычно связан с куками, нужно получать и отправлять их вместе

Comment: Он находится как атрибут тега body,

Comment: @andreymal и еще он действует пока активна сессия

Comment: это защита не от ботов, а от csrf-атаки

Answer (score -1):

Делаешь 1 запрос на сайт (на страницу авторизации, к примеру), сохраняешь токен и куки, затем отправляешь запрос на авторизацию вместе с куками (это важно!) и полученным токеном, должно сработать. Это базовая защита от парсинга и т.д.

Comment: Там как бы сказать, токен с авторизацией вообще никак не связан)

Comment: Он именно в пост запросе при отправке сообщения используется

Comment: Ну авторизация как и отправка сообщения - определенное действие, которое как раз и проверяется на защиту от ботов. Перед ним нужно просто получить токен и с куками, при которых ты получил токен, отправить запрос.

Comment: Хорошо попробую